# Conditions for convergence of complex sequence

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

I want to show

\begin{equation}
1 + (\phi z)^{-1} + (\phi z)^{-2} + …
\end{equation}

converges to $\frac{1}{1- (\phi z)^{-1}}$ when $|\phi| > 1$ and $z \geq 1$.

What I tried is

\begin{align*}
1 + (\phi z)^{-1} + (\phi z)^{-2} + … & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n} (\phi z)^{-i}\\
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1 - (\phi z)^{-(n+1)}}{ 1- (\phi z)^{-1}}
\end{align*}

I can see that $(\phi z)^{-(n+1)}$ converges to zero when $|\phi| > 1$ and $z \geq 1$ and thus the result is verified. However, what would happen when $|\phi| \geq 1$ and $z > 1$. To me it seems still converges.

Edit: I am trying to prove this from a book.

[image]

However, I don't really see why this condition has to be this way. Why can't it be $|\phi| \geq 1$ and $|z| > 1$. Aren't they equivalent?

Comment: Seems fine to me. The second case is the same one.

Comment: However, I am not really sure why the book mention that $|\phi| > 1, |z| \geq 1$.

Comment: The book did not exclude the second case. S/he  just pick one case as your exercise. If no additional conditions, then these are exactly the same, since the choice of alphabets have nothing to do with the result.

Comment: Avoid using the index $i$ when working in complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the whole question can be handled with $w:=(\phi z)^{-1}$ such that $|w|<1$ (which is compatible with $|\phi|>1,|z|\ge1$).

Then

$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^nw^k\right|\le\sum_{k=0}^n\left|w\right|^k<\frac1{1-|w|}.$$